# Pasting text with the mouse doesn't trigger search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, selectize.js

For selectize.js with ajax search inserting text by mouse not cause search

It's can be simle reproduced on http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js page.
On **Remote Source — Github** example:

1. focus on field
2. delete selected
3. insert text any text by mouse (not
   by ctrl+v)
4. no result

How to fix it?

Update

For catching event by jquery **bind** method. Selectize **on** method can't catch it (bug?).

```
$('.selectize').bind('input', function(){
// force selectize to make ajax call and show result  
});

// following code catch nothing
$('.selectize')[0].selectize.on('input', function(){
// force selectize to make ajax call   
});
```

But can't find solution for forcing selectize ajax call

Comment: You can probably manually trigger the search method from the mouse events. https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: @isherwood Yes, I can catch the event, but how to kick the selectize to load data? Also, with simpe propertychange event it can produce double server call

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can find fix on the issue page https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/882

the code

```
onPaste: function(e) {
        var self = this;
        if (self.isFull() || self.isInputHidden || self.isLocked) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            // If a regex or string is included, this will split the pasted
            // input and create Items for each separate value
             setTimeout(function() {
                 if (self.settings.splitOn) {
                    var splitInput = $.trim(self.$control_input.val() || '').split(self.settings.splitOn);
                    for (var i = 0, n = splitInput.length; i < n; i++) {
                        self.createItem(splitInput[i]);
                    }
                  }
                  self.onKeyUp(e);
            }, 0);
        }
    },
```